# django upload a file from other python script

Tags: django, python-requests

I want to save file from the client to the django project server's database from a script. I've tried to do this using a model and a view in the django project, and post request in the other python script, but it keeps return 403 error and not save the file and the data to the database.

models.py:

```
class ScreenRecord(models.Model):
        record = models.FileField(default='output.avi', upload_to='records')
        writeTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

views.py:

```
def getscreenrecords(request):
    user = User.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('user')).first()
    k = ScreenRecord(record=request.FILES.get('record'), user=user)
    k.save()
    return HttpResponse('success ' + request.GET.__getitem__('user'))
```

url.py:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('screenrecords/', views.getscreenrecords, name='getscreenrecords'),
]
```

python script to send the file:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/send/screenrecords/'
files = {'record': open('output.avi','rb')}
values = {'user': 'newUser'}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=values)
print(r)
```

what's wrong in my code or is there a way to do this better?

Comment: Where is this function 'screenrecords'?
try the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/send/getscreenrecords/

Comment: the url is like this: path('screenrecords/', views.getscreenrecords, name='getscreenrecords'). .../send/getscreenrecords returns 404 error

Comment: This should be related to CSRF.

Comment: can you share your urls.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django needs a CSRF token in POST requests by default.

Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it) for more info on how to use it on your requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass csrf_token along with the data passed in your js, if you are doing it within the Django project, here is a sample code to do it.

```
 <script>
    var token = '{{csrf_token}}';

    $("#id_username").change(function () {
      console.log($(this).val());
      var form = $(this).closest("form");
      $.ajax({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
        url: form.attr("data-validate-username-url"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_taken) {
            alert(data.error_message);
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```